# SQL and PHP problem on selected item :Notice: Trying to get property 'profession' of non-object

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm looking for help to fix a problem I have, this "Notice: Trying to get property 'profession' of non-object" error is occuring in my code:

```
if ($i==1){
        $select = $db->prepare("Select distinct profession from contact where affiliation='nord' order by profession"); // I get all professions from the database
        $select->execute();
    }
    $data = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $profess=$data->profession; // i take the next profession
```

I think it has something to do with my query returning an array but looking at exemples, I can't see how it can be fixed here. Hoping you guys can help me, thx (i'm a beginner so the error might be flagrant)

Comment: Move the last 2 lines into your if check. If `$i` is not 1, then `$select` will not exist.

Comment: The same error is ocurring, the value of $i starts with 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the block of code in if condition to eliminate the notice, actually your were facing issue because your if condition were not true and the rest of code execute that's why

```
if ($i==1){
        $select = $db->prepare("Select distinct profession from contact where affiliation='nord' order by profession"); // I get all professions from the database
        $select->execute();
   
        $data = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $profess=$data->profession; // i take the next profession
 }
```